# Unable to register .in domain in Godaddy Module

Tags: whmcs, godaddy-api

I am using Godaddy Module to Register Domain Name. While Registering  .in domain i am getting following error

"Order Accept Encountered Problems
Request body doesn't fulfill schema, see details in `fields`

- body.privacy does not exist in the schema

"

i did some google and it is related to privacy protection option, but since my client don't want privacy protection how i overcome this error

Please explain me how to solve this error thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.whmcs.com/GoDaddy#Request_body_doesn.27t_fulfill_schema.2C_see_details_in_fields and 
https://github.com/srvrco/getssl/issues/378

Comment: I go through first link but all info are correct beside that privacy field is giving error